# Compass watch detects change twice (right after compile)?

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I have a drupal sub-theme (omega) which works with sass-compass. When I go to my theme folder and run "compass watch" it always detects a change (eventhough it says all compiled css files are identical. When I change something to my scss, it detects the change and re-compiles the changed file(s) but right after the compile, it always detects a change and checks the files again.

If my explanation is not 100% clear, please check the cmd lines below:

```
C:\webserver\htdocs\mysite\sites\all\themes\my_theme>compass watch
>>> Change detected at 10:05:28 to: my-theme.no-query.scss
identical css/my-theme.no-query.css
identical css/my-theme.normalize.css
identical css/my-theme.styles.css
>>> Compass is polling for changes. Press Ctrl-C to Stop.
>>> Change detected at 10:05:39 to: my-theme.styles.scss
overwrite css/my-theme.no-query.css
identical css/my-theme.normalize.css
overwrite css/my-theme.styles.css
>>> Change detected at 10:05:42 to: my-theme.styles.scss ( << why is this happening)
identical css/my-theme.no-query.css
identical css/my-theme.normalize.css
identical css/my-theme.styles.css
```

As you can see from the cmd-lines, the last change detected is 3 seconds after the actual change ... whenever I change anything to my scss, it detects the change, recompiles and immeditaly detects another change, even though there hasn't been any.

I this normal behaviour (seems strange to me) and if it's not, what could be causing this?

This isn't a problem in the sense that the compiled css files are correct but I installed livereload and this also seems to detected multiple changes causing the site to reload twice.

Update:

I added the --dry-run flagwhich gave me this:

```
C:\webserver\htdocs\mysite\sites\all\themes\my_theme>compass watch --dry-run
>>> Change detected at 10:05:28 to: my-theme.no-query.scss
identical css/my-theme.no-query.css
identical css/my-theme.normalize.css
identical css/my-theme.styles.css
>>> Change detected at 10:05:39 to: my-theme.styles.scss
overwrite css/my-theme.no-query.css
identical css/my-theme.normalize.css
overwrite css/my-theme.styles.css
>>> Change detected at 10:05:42 to: my-theme.styles.scss ( << why is this happening)
overwrite css/my-theme.no-query.css
identical css/my-theme.normalize.css
overwrite css/my-theme.styles.css
```

in other words, it seems to ALWAYS run twice after the initial compass watch change detection.

Comment: Which editor are you using? Does it use some sort of auto-save?

Comment: @TheConstructor eclipse, no auto-save involved.

Comment: Same problem here, I use PhpStorm with autosave but this is not the origin of the problem: the watch events are fired twice even with vim from the command line with no sort of autosave. Did someone has solved this issue ?

Comment: @bgondy I still havn't figured out the problem ... I just learned to live with it. Are you also working on an Omega sub-theme perhaps? Still thinking it has something to do with it.

I just can't understand nobody else seems to have this problem, I've searched high and low for info on this.

Comment: No, it's a theme from scratch. What is strange is that I have the problem only on my desktop machine running a Debian VM but not at home when the two PCs run the same VM (clone of the desktop VM). They only have a few settings differences.